# How to write a Drupal module to process uploaded file?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'd like to add a `Process` button next to a uploaded file. When the user click the `Process` button, it triggers my module by passing the location of the attached file to a function/hook in my module to further process the file.

Is there an existing module I can use as an example? Or how can I start from scratch?

Comment: I'd vouch for @CristobalWetzig's advice. I would have adviced the same thing. It sounds complex, but once you see the examples in Drupal.org for those hook implementations you will see that it's pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a module for that:

If you mean an already uploaded file to a node, and for an already uploaded file, and it should be handled on a buttonpress.

**Sketch**:

In your module:
Create a hook_form_alter that takes the node edit form and add your process button with the help of the form-api.(adding a form element)

There you can access the file information since you have access to the node and send that to a menu callback created in a hook_menu that processes the file. (by passing it to your custom process function)

Hooks:

- [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6)
- [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6)
- [FormApi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6)